# iOS - Rotate 3D object in scenekit

Tags: ios, scenekit

Hi I'm trying to rotate a 3D object in scenekit with no success heres my code:

```
    let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateByAngle(90, aroundAxis: SCNVector3Make(0, 1, 0), duration: 3)
    let moveAction = SCNAction.moveByX(25, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 6)

    ship.runAction(rotateAction, completionHandler: {ship.runAction(moveAction)})
```

I have managed to get it rotating on the correct axis but for some reason its not rotating by the 90 degrees that I've stated it just spins numerous times for the 3 seconds. I appreciate any help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the angle for rotateByAngle  is in radians, so for 90 degrees you'd have to make the angle 1.571 radians.

if you'd like to be more thorough, add a little function to convert degrees to radians. it also will make the code easier to understand in the future.

```
func degToRadians(degrees:Double) -> Double
{
    return degrees * (M_PI / 180);
}
```

[SCNAction Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNAction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNAction/rotateByAngle:aroundAxis:duration:)

Comment: Swift defines M_PI_2 for Pi/2 (90 degrees). Better to use that symbolic definition rather than 1.571.

Comment: Thanks to both of you all working now, any chance either of you know how to add a 2D image into the scene?